# Score box and question box are misaligned on the flags page

Tags: bug, design

The score box and the question title box have different heights on the flags page (see image below). Also, if the score is negative, the text wraps inside its box.

[image]

OS: 10.6.8
Browser: Safari 5.1.7
Extensions: Ghostery (But even with it disabled, the bug is still present.)

Comment: Odd - I've never seen that - would you mind editing in your OS version, browser details (version) and whether you have any extensions or plug in that might be affecting things?